# Groups occuring as derived subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to solve this problem but I have no idea how to start it. If you know please hint me, thanks.

> Suppose that $G$ is a group that has subgroup which is cyclic, characteristic and not in the center of $G$. Prove that there does not exist a group $K$ such that $K^{\prime}\cong G$, where $K^{\prime}$ is the derived (commutator) subgroup of $K$.

Comment: What does $K'$ here mean?

Comment: @sleevechen I think that it is the derived subgroup of $K$. However, I am not sure.

Comment: @sleevechen:commutator of $K$

Comment: A more general result can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361582/which-groups-are-derived-subgroups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that there exists a group $K$ such that $G \cong K'$.
Then $K'$ has a cyclic characteristic subgroup $N \subseteq K'$ not contained in the center of $K'$.

Now, $N$ is characteristic in $K'$, and $K'$ is characteristic in $K$, so $N$ is normal in $K$. So, by [this result](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Derived_subgroup_centralizes_normal_subgroup_whose_automorphism_group_is_abelian) $K'$ is contained in the centralizer $C_K(N)$, so $N$ is contained in the center of $K$. A contradiction.